Как перебирать кортежи в c++?
Можете объяснить как перебирать кортежи в языке c++? Мне необходимо создать кортеж из 6 элементов и, в зависимости от условия, добавлять или заменять элемент в кортеже. В конце вывести все элементы.
Задание 1. Кортежи
Соревнования по игре «Тетрис-онлайн» проводятся по следующим правилам.
Каждый участник регистрируется на сайте игры под определённым игровым именем. Имена участников не повторяются.
Чемпионат проводится в течение определённого времени. В любой момент этого времени любой зарегистрированный участник может зайти на сайт чемпионата и начать зачётную игру. По окончании игры её результат (количество набранных очков) фиксируется и заносится в протокол.
Участники имеют право играть несколько раз. Количество попыток одного участника не ограничивается.
Окончательный результат участника определяется по одной игре, лучшей для данного участника.
Более высокое место в соревнованиях занимает участник, показавший лучший результат.
При равенстве результатов более высокое место занимает участник, раньше показавший лучший результат.
В ходе соревнований заполняется протокол, каждая строка которого описывает одну игру и содержит результат участника и его игровое имя. Протокол формируется в реальном времени по ходу проведения чемпионата, поэтому строки в нём расположены в порядке проведения игр: чем раньше встречается строка в протоколе, тем раньше закончилась соответствующая этой строке игра.
Напишите эффективную, в том числе по памяти, программу, которая по данным протокола определяет победителя и призёров. Гарантируется, что в чемпионате участвует не менее трёх игроков.
Перед текстом программы кратко опишите алгоритм решения задачи и укажите используемый язык программирования и его версию.
Описание входных данных
Первая строка содержит число N- общее количество строк протокола. Каждая из следующих N строк содержит записанные через пробел результат участника (целое неотрицательное число, не превышающее 100 миллионов) и игровое имя (имя не может содержать пробелов). Строки исходных данных соответствуют строкам протокола и расположены в том же порядке, что и в протоколе.
Гарантируется, что количество участников соревнований не меньше 3.
Описание выходных данных
Программа должна вывести имена и результаты трёх лучших игроков по форме, приведённой ниже в примере.
Пример входных данных:
9
69485 Jack
95715 qwerty
95715 Alex
83647 M
197128 qwerty
95715 Jack
93289 Alex
95715 Alex
95715 M
Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных данных:
1 место. qwerty (197128)
2 место. Alex (95715)
3 место. Jack (95715)
Со своими скудными знаниями, я смог додуматься только до этого.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int N, i, score;
    string username;
    tuple<int, string, int, string, int, string> t(0, "name", 0, "name", 0, "name");
    cout << "Введите количество строк --> ";
    cin >> N;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> score >> username;
        if (score > get<0>(t))
        {
            if (get<1>(t) != username)
            {
                if ((get<0>(t) > get<2>(t)))
                {
                    get<2>(t) = get<0>(t);
                    get<3>(t) = get<1>(t);
                }
                else if ((get<0>(t) > get<4>(t)) && (get<1>(t) != get<3>(t)))
                {
                    get<4>(t) = get<0>(t);
                    get<5>(t) = get<1>(t);
                }
            }
            get<0>(t) = score;
            get<1>(t) = username;
        }
        else if (get<1>(t) != username)
        {
            if (score > get<2>(t))
            {
                if ((get<2>(t) > get<4>(t)) && (get<3>(t) != get<1>(t)))
                {
                    get<4>(t) = get<2>(t);
                    get<5>(t) = get<3>(t);
                }
                get<2>(t) = score;
                get<3>(t) = username;
            }
            else if ((score > get<4>(t)) && (username != get<3>(t)))
            {
                get<4>(t) = score;
                get<5>(t) = username;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "1 место. " << get<1>(t) << " (" << get<0>(t) << ")" << endl;
    cout << "2 место. " << get<3>(t) << " (" << get<2>(t) << ")" << endl;
    cout << "3 место. " << get<5>(t) << " (" << get<4>(t) << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}


Добавьте какой-то код в вопрос. Ну там создание кортежей, например, которые вы планируете перебирать.

Непонятно, что вы хотите. Может, как сгенерировать все кортежи длины N из элементов данного множества. Может, с повторениями. Может, без. Может, у вас есть множество кортежей и вы хотите их перебрать. Может, вам надо это... Что вы хотите? При таком вот ТЗ ответ один: ХЗ...

В следующий раз сразу пишите всю информацию в вопрос, а не после того, как кто-то напишет ответ. Размер и типы элементов кортежа фиксированы во время компиляции. Если вы собрались в рантайме что-то менять, вам наверное больше подойдет std::vector<std::variant<...>>. Можете подробнее рассказать, для чего это?

@HolyBlackCat Простите за это. Мне по заданию необходимо работать с кортежем. В университете выдали задание на кортежи. Если необходимо, могу отправить само задание.

Да, добавьте задание, плиз.

В кортеж невозможно добавить элемент: Типы данных для элементов, включая их количество, задаются на этапе компиляции.  Можно только поменять значение элемента. Или можно создать новый кортеж, добавив новый элемент (но не модифицировать старый).

У меня известен тип и количество. Надо только элемент поменять, на другой элемент такого-же типа

Вы перемудрили, от вас никто не требует использовать кортежи. (Если вы весь текст задания показали.) Возможно под кортежами они имели в виду в том числе структуры (подошло бы что-то типа struct Game {std::string name; int score;}). Ну можете вместо структуры взять std::tuple<std::string, int>, разницы никакой, просто чуть менее удобный код. В остальном, это задачка на поиск N максимальных элементов (в гугле должны быть алгоритмы).

Присвоить значение элементу 1 :  std::get<1>(t) = "12232". Но: Вам ненужен кортеж из 6 элементов. Вам нужен массив из 3 элементов, (кортежей/структур из 2-х элементов).

Возможно мне надо сначала найти этих трёх игроков, и только потом их добавить в кортеж и вывести, а не добавлять и проверять. Я просто думал, что эта задача похожа на задачи с массивами и сделал так. Если что, потом спрошу у преподавателя.

Нет смысла сначала добавлять в кортеж, а потом выводить, если можно сразу вывести.

Я знаю, но мне надо как-то использовать кортеж. Придётся подумать.

Вам устно сказали, что нужно, или вы из-за Задание 1. Кортежи так думаете?
